# How to add a client javascript globally to a xpages application

Tags: xpages

I have added a javascript library by using copy-paste to an xpage application within Designer Java view.
However this does not seems to work, because  the source is wrong in the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/development/charts/HighChartsTest.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/.js/js%2Fjquery190min.js&amp;js%2Fjs%2Fhighcharts.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/development/charts/HighChartsTest.nsf/js/jquery190min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/development/charts/HighChartsTest.nsf/js/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

the theme used by the application contains the following lines:

```
<resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>/js/jquery190min.js</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>/js/js/highcharts.js</href>
    </resource>
```

What causes this and how to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the resource aggregation. To disable this feature you have to open the *Application properies*, select the *XPages* section and disable the option *Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources*

But keep in mind that this will affect the performance of your application.